# 401 Authorization Required on REST client

Tags: spring, web-services, rest, web

I am trying to write a very simple REST client using `RestTemplate` and Jackson JSON.
Tried such sample from `spring.io` Getting **error 401 Authorization Required** even on localhost or even if I include it into the same `Tomcat6 Eclipse` project where that `REST WebService` is running.

We don't require any authorization on that Web Service while in Dev or local environment,
and anyway I am an authorized user.

Is that something enforced by `Spring RestTemplate`?

Running client as Java application on Java 1.6.

I am new to REST and JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no enforced `Authorization` required by Spring's `RestTemplate`. You should be able to build or launch an example simple REST webservice and send requests to it with `RestTemplate` without receiving this response, so either the server you are sending the requests to or something inbetween is returning this response code. Can you share any more details of the service you are communicating with? Is it something internal or a public API which may require Authorization?